# Moving of Actor LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, game-physics

Please, help me with my issue.
I need to move an Actor to special coordinates. I use Stage, so what can I do to solve my problem.

If I'd use OrthographicCamera and rectangle, I'd wrote something like that:

```
Rectangle myRect = .........
while (myRect.y >= 10) {
myRect.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
}
```

I want to use something like this with Actor. Please, help me. Thank everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibGDX provides a bunch of Actions that you can perform on Actors. For moving an actor to a specific location you can use MoveToAction. With this you can set the final location and also how long it it takes to move to that location.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/MoveToAction.html

```
MoveToAction action = new MoveToAction();
action.setY(10); // y-position to move to
action.setDuration(duration); // time (in seconds) to move there

actor.addAction(action);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try to use it.

Comment: @PashaOleynik you may use `Actions.moveTo(...)` instead to simplify you code.

Comment: @desertkun no, I can't. Because moveTo() only set a new position for my Actor. I want to move my Actor with animation, for Example: we have raindrop, and it must fall from top to down of the screen. If I use moveTo(), my raindrop will be immediately rendered in new position (down of the screen) without falling.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code doesn't work :(
Maybe, I missed something important? I read the docs and try to use setTime(time) instead of setDuration, but it not been successful. 
My Actors not even change their position, not to mention about their visual movements on the screen.

Comment: @PashaOleynik sorry for miscommunication here, what I did mean is to write something like this: `actor.addAction(Actions.moveTo(duration, 0, 10))` instead of writing bunch of blocks. Just simplify things.

Comment: @desertkun, oh, now i understand your idea, thnx.

Comment: That's strange, this code works for me (using setDuration)...can you post your code?

Comment: @Tekkerue, this is my code:

                `MoveToAction moveActor = new MoveToAction();`
                `moveActor.setPosition(10f, 10f);`
                `moveActor.setDuration(10f);`
                `group1.addAction(moveActor);`

Comment: Your code works when I applied it to an Image. It doesn't move very much if you don't set an initial position for the actor because the default position is (0,0) and moving to (10,10) over 10 seconds is only 1 pixel per second. Try making the MoveToAction bigger like (500,500) or something and see if it moves. If not, then there's something else going on with the actor.

Comment: @Tekkerue, I try to use this code to another actor and it works. So, I'll search the problems with Actor. 
Excuse for troubling.

Comment: No trouble at all. :) Were you able to get it working yet? If not, then could you post some more info about "group1", it sounds like this is where the problem is occurring. Is this a custom Actor you created? Did you override the act(float delta) method? The act method is where the Actions are applied to the Actor, so if you did override it you need to call super.act(delta) within your method to apply the Actions.

Comment: @Tekkerue, yes, this code working well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

LibGDX also provides a shorter way of doing it.

```
actor.addAction(Actions.moveTo(actor.getX(), 10, duration));
```

Comment: This was is also better because it takes advantage of memory pooling.